# How to programmatically crossfade between songs

Tags: iphone, media-player

I am working on a music player for the iPhone, and I would like to crossfade between songs. I know this is possible because My DJ does it...I can't find any documentation and don't even know where to begin on it. Can anyone give me a starting point or example code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert both songs into raw (linear PCM) samples.  Then build your own mixer function or audio unit where the mix ratio of each sample comes from a ramp or custom mix curve function.  Feed the output to the RemoteIO audio unit.

Comment: Bounced. I didn't understand anything. Could you please explore a bit.