# How do I fade between songs in IOS?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

The question is pretty direct.  How can I fade between songs on IOS?  I assume it's using MPMusicPlayerController, but I can't figure out the appropriate controls.  I can start a song, stop it, etc etc, but I can't fade it in/out (I know about the volume property, but trying to evenly fade that out relies on NSTimer firing more than once a second), much less fade one song out while the next fades in.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395375/how-can-i-fade-out-the-sound-played-by-mpmusicplayercontroller

Comment: Not quite; I need to fade one song in WHILE the next fades out.  While the first 'half' of the question could be considered  a duplicate, the second half is, IMO, the more important one.

Comment: Then you need two MPMusicPlayers

Comment: I'm going to go run an experiment, because for some reason I thought you couldn't have two at once.

Comment: Oh...if that's true I will feel awfully stupid ><;

Comment: Well here, this post suggests that you should use AVAudioPlayer instead:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744736/how-to-programmatically-crossfade-between-songs

Comment: If you intend to play tracks from your iPod music library, then `AVPlayer` is the way to go rather than `AVAudioPlayer`

Comment: @borrrden Yes you are right. But how can i create two instances of MPMusciPlayerController???